# Firebase Auth and Database Encryption

Tags: android, encryption, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have started developing an application powered by Google's Firebase services. I am curious if the data transmission is secure within the Auth and database services. If not, are there any sources to material that I can read to possibly implement encryption?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All traffic between the app and the Authentication and Database services goes over HTTPS. This ensures it is an end-to-end secured connection.